# Why system halts and reports cannot allocate memory

Tags: bash

I tried the following bash code in my terminal:

```
:()
{
: | : &
};
:
```

The systems halts and reports:

> bash fork: cannot allocate memory

Could anyone explain to me why the above code keeps forking and using out all system memory?

Thanks.

Comment: [Fork bomb?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-the-command-make-my-system-lag-so-badly-i-had-to-reboot)

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, but I would like to understand why

Comment: The answers to the linked question explain why very well :)

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks. I saw that. This is fun

Comment: This is also BashFAQ #59: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/059